# Root can only change a file

Tags: permissions

I'm trying to make it so only a few php files can only be changed with the root user, however I had no luck.. The user I set up through adduser in ssh is still able to change/view it.

I've used the following command:

```
sudo chown root:root /home/website/public_html/game1/donate.php
```

The new user is in a different group which is websitegroup1

Is there anything im doing wrong?

Comment: That is only part of permissions showing owner and group set to root. What is the file's mode?

Comment: Not only that, but if the user has write permission to the directory the file is in, they can just move (or delete) the file and make a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give permissions to that file:

```
sudo chmod 0644 /home/website/public_html/game1/donate.php
```

In this way, only `root` will be able to change the file.

If you also want to not give read access to other users do:

```
sudo chmod 0600 /home/website/public_html/game1/donate.php
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there also a way preventing the user from downloading it? So it shows something like Permission denied?

www-data should still have access to it as it's a page where users can buy ingame credits/points.

Comment: What are the containing directory path permissions? If the new user can delete and recreate the file, the existing file permissions are useless. The 600 permissions will prevent non-root users from viewing (assuming you've done the chown as well).

Comment: @Manolo Salsas - If i do the second line in ssh, nginx returns a Access Denied message.

Comment: @mpez0 - haven't thought about that. Is there a way to set up that the file can not be deleted unless its being deleted by an 'root' user?

Comment: @Codemunkie - There is a way to do what you want: You have to put the file outside the document root, and access it with a script.

Comment: @Codemunkie - The second line probably gives you that message because you are not `root`.

Comment: And yes. There is a way to deny deleting the file to the users. Use the sticky bit. e.g. `sudo chmod 1644 /home/website/public_html/game1/donate.php`

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer if it has been useful.

Comment: You're very welcome ;)